# sql::mysql::get_driver_instance() Symbol not found

Tags: c++, mysql, xcode, linker

I'm trying to link the mysql native API to my server software now... With little luck. When compiling in Xcode on OSX10.9 using the flags

> $(OTHER_CFLAGS) -I /usr/local/boost_1_55_0/ -I
>   /usr/local/mysqlconn/include/ -I /usr/local/mysqlconn/lib/

I get the compiler/linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "sql::mysql::get_driver_instance()", referenced from:
>         sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance() in SQLComm.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I really have no idea why though. The API files were downloaded by me today, and extracted at the included paths. I include all the files from include and include/cppconn in the server program that uses the function the linker cannot found.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you configuring include directories, but I don't see any libraries listed there.

You need to link in the library when you build your project.

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold: .... no. Why don't you read the documentation? They will have detailed explanations and examples on how to use the library. Don't just randomly guess. If I were to be forced to do that, I would guess `-lmysqlconn`. By the way, I can recommend [the MySQL++ wrapper](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/).

Comment: The documentation, read I have. Solution, found I have not. Thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold: Looks like it's `-lmysqlcppconn`. [Read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-unix.html).

Comment: Thanks. I built the files for i386 and attempted to link them on x86_64 it seems.

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold: Whoops :)